# Trying to reduce else if for errors into one

Tags: java, if-statement

For the code below I am trying to reduce redundancies by putting the return errors into one else statement. Is there any way to do this? This is for an RPN calculator, with numbers being added to an array and if an operator is used, it will call a method to use that operator with the numbers in the listInput array.

```
      public String nextOperation() {
            for (String listInput : listInputs) {
                if (isLong(listInput)) {
                    if (current == null) {
                        current = new RPN(Long.parseLong(listInput));
                    } else {
                        addToStack(current, Long.parseLong(listInput));
                    }
                } else if (isBasicOperator(listInput)) {
                    if (current == null) {
                        return "Error: too few operands";
                    } else {
                        eval.evaluateBasic(current, listInput);
                    }
                } else {
                    if(isOperator(listInput)){
                        eval.evaluateRepeat(current,listInput);
                    }else{
                        return "Error: bad token " + "'" + listInput + "'";
                    }
                }
            }
            return getOutput();
        }
```

Comment: You are returning two different error messages right now. Putting them into the same else branch means that you will only return one kind of error message. Is that expected?

Comment: you can unfold the last else: `else { if (isOperator(listInput)) { eval.evaluateRepeat(current,listInput);} else { return "Error: bad token " + "'" + listInput + "'"; }  }` can become `else  if (isOperator(listInput)) { eval.evaluateRepeat(current,listInput); } else { return "Error: bad token " + "'" + listInput + "'"; }`

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? You could throw and exception in the called method, which would be better encapsulation, if that's more of a redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Instinctively, I'll go for the classic refactoring [replace conditional with inheritance](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). Once this refactoring is done, you will be able to see more clearly if there is redundancy to avoid.

Something like this:

```
public class LongOperator extends Operator {

  @Override
  public String nextOperation() {
    addToStack(current, Long.parseLong(listInput));
    return super.getOutput();
  }
}

public class NullLongOperator extends NullOperator {

  @Override
  public String nextOperation() {
    return "Error: too few operands";
  }
}

public class BasicOperator extends Operator {

  @Override
  public String nextOperation() {
    eval.evaluateBasic(current, listInput);
    return super.getOutput();
  }
}
etc.
```

With a factory method in Operator or anything similar to instantiate the right operator. This way, you will be able to grow the logic in each operator and stop worrying about your if/else since they will be clearly expressed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the proposed refactor to classes, which isn't always a practical solution. Roughly:

```java
public void handleLong(String listInput) {
  if (current == null) {
    current = new RPN(Long.parseLong(listInput));
  } else {
    addToStack(current, Long.parseLong(listInput));
  }
}

public void handleBasic(String listInput) {
  if (current == null) {
    throw new SomeRuntimeException("Error: too few operands");
  }

  eval.evaluateBasic(current, listInput);
}

public void handleOp(String listInput) {
  if (!isOperator(listInput)) {
    throw SomeRuntimeException("Error: bad token '" + listInput + "'");
  }

  eval.evaluateRepeat(current, listInput);
}

public String nextOperation() {
  for (String listInput : listInputs) {
    try {
      if (isLong(listInput)) {
        handleLong(listInput);
      } else if (isBasicOperator(listInput)) {
        handleBasic(listInput);
      } else {
        handleOp(listInput);
      }
    } catch (SomeRuntimeException e) {
      return e.getMessage()
    }
  }
  
  return getOutput();
}
```

Which makes more sense? Depends on context.

Do you have the time to restructure your code to a mini class explosion? It may touch many areas.

Do you need to maintain the contract you currently have? Wrap the broken-out code in a try-catch and handle each type separately. Not as clean as a complete refactoring, but very practical, incrementally easier to deal with than what's there (which isn't that horrible anyway).

Can you change the calling code to handle the exception? Remove the try-catch from here and handle it elsewhere.

Is it a *development* error if this happens? Maybe don't catch the exception at all.